# Delete log file when script closes?

Tags: bash, logging

- I have a script that logs its status to a file every minute.
- A statusbar then displays the contents of this log.

When the script is aborted, the log is no loger of interest to me, because it's outdated. I want it deleted.

Would it be possible to have a file that exists only if a script is running and disappears otherwise?

I know that I could write another script that would periodically delete the log, but I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'rm /path/to/log' EXIT TERM

# ...
```

Comment: with `trap 'rm /path/to/log' 0 1 2 3 15`, my script no longer terminates with ^C. It works as expected with `trap 'rm /path/to/log' EXIT TERM`, though.

Comment: Actually `trap 'cmd...' EXIT` is enough. It'll cover exits caused by `INT`, `TERM`, ... And `trap 'cmd...' EXIT TERM` will run the cmd **twice** if the script is killed by `TERM`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the trap mentioned by "sputnick" you might also want the file to be explicitly temporary. The downside to a temp file is that it will likely end up with an inconvenient path , which would matter if you want to be able to do stuff with it on a commandline.

To make a temp file, use `mktemp`, along these lines:

```
tempFile="$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}$(basename "$0")-XXXXX")"
```

This will (a) include the name of your script in the temporary file name, and (b) use `$TMPDIR` as a base directory if set but default to `/tmp` as is generally good practice.

As for the `trap`, I think the main signal you should care about is `TERM`, and you'll also want to catch the pseudo-signal `EXIT`. I prefer using the signal names to their less portable numbers:

```
trap 'rm -f "${tempFile}"' EXIT TERM
```